# IS there an easy way to call a method from one component in vue to another

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have two components, `App.Vue` and `CoinList.vue`, but I'm having some problems calling a method, here's the code:

snippet of `App.vue`

```
<q-list>
        <q-item clickable v-close-popup @click="cct">
           <q-item-section avatar>
          ₦
        </q-item-section>

        <q-item-section>NAIRA</q-item-section>
        </q-item>

        <q-item clickable v-close-popup @click="changeToUsd()">
           <q-item-section avatar>
          $
        </q-item-section>

        <q-item-section>USD</q-item-section>
        </q-item>

        <q-item clickable v-close-popup @click="changeToEur()">
          <q-item-section avatar>
          €
        </q-item-section>

        <q-item-section>EUR</q-item-section>
        </q-item>
      </q-list>
```

snippet of `CoinList.vue`

```
methods: {
    getCoinsData: function () {
     ...
    },
    changeToNgn: function () {
    ...
    },
    changeToUsd: function () {
     ...
    },
    changeToEur: function () {
    ...
    },
  },
```

I want the click event in `App.vue` to call the function in `CoinList.vue` but it seems not to be working.
I read somewhere about the event bus but I just couldn't seem to get the hang of it, If there's anyway I could be helped, I'll really appreciate it.

Comment: I don;t see where you use `CoinList`

Comment: I used it earlier in `App.vue`, just posted a snippet of the relevant click events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call a child component method using `ref` directive like this:

Indicate `ref`:

```
<coin-list ref="coinList" />
```

Use it

```
changeToEur () {
  this.$refs.coinList.changeToUsd()
}
```